# How to make remmina ignore a key?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vnc, remote-desktop

I like to use the F12 key to bring up an instant yakuake terminal.

However, if I use remmina to start a remote GUI session, if the remmina window is active, then F12 won't bring up the terminal, because the key is captured by remmina.

How can I make remmina ignore this key so that it is seen by the OS?

Answer (score 0):

I made a workaround using Autohotkey and Python for switching desktops. Autohotkey on the client grabs the key and sends a packet to the Python server on the host. You should be able to adjust it for your usecase.

Note: Sometimes the client seems to get a modifier key stuck when switching to the host. Like what happens sometimes when Super/Windows goes to the host for some reason.

https://github.com/thomasa88/remote_linux_desktop_switch